# Regex pattern to exclude a list of words anywhere in the string

Tags: regex, google-forms

I'm trying to prevent user registering using their personal email like google or yahoo or etc.... for the event.

The regex I have been using with

```
^((?!gmail|yahoo).)*$
```

but it doesn't prevent user from entering valid email.

I know how to match valid email pattern that contains yahoo and gmail that I do not want to match.

`^[\w\.\-].{0,}@(yahoo|gmail)\.[\w\.\-].{0,}$`

Above pattern match below strings

```
johndoe@yahoo.com (match)
john@gmail.com (match)
john (unmatch)
john@g. (unmatch)
johndoe@company.com (unmatch) <- This is the thing I want to match
```

How do I reverse the above pattern to match only company email instead of personal email.

Comment: Maybe `^[\w.-]+@(?!(yahoo|gmail)\.[\w.-]+$)[\w.-]+\.\w{2,}$` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/stTYsu/1))?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks it does work. Is there any workaround using without negative lookahead? Actually I'm trying to add this pattern on google form regex pattern but it does not contains negative lookahead. 
Syntax for Regular Expressions for google form
https://support.google.com/a/answer/1371415?hl=en

Comment: No, Google Forms regex is RE2 powered, so no way to support lookaheads.

Answer (score -1):

If I understood the question correctly possible solution is the following:

```
[\w\-.]+@company\.com
```

Where:

```
[...] - any characters inside brackets
\w - a-z, 0-9, _
+ - 1 or more characters
```

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/PGksro/1)